# How to set JAVA_HOME in a bat file before accessing Java

Tags: portability, minecraft, java-home

I am making a portable minecraft that works completely off a flash drive, including java. At my home computer the .bat file works perfectly, however on the school computer it does not run and gives me "java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file" leading me to believe that the batch is looking for java on the local computer as apposed to my intentions of using the java portable installed on the flash drive.

Here is my code.

```
@echo off
Title Do not close this window
set APPDATA=%CD%\mcp_data
set JAVA_HOME=%CD%\mcp_data\Java\bin

java -Xmx3072M -jar "%CD%\mcp_data\launcher\MineCraft.jar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the PATH variable to include java anywhere. Your home system knows where to find a copy of java (because it's most likely installed on your machine too) but the school system doesn't.

So you can either try and change the path variables on the school computer (which you may or may not have the rights to do, and it leaves a trail they might not like), or you can make your bat file refer to the copy of Java on the flash drive by it's full path name, i.e. `%CD%\mcp_data\Java\bin\java.exe` or whatever the path of the java executable is.

I recommend using the full path name since it's in a bat file, so the fact that it's longer doesn't really matter.

See below.

```
@echo off
Title DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW!!! Closing this window will force close MineCraft
set APPDATA=%CD%/mcp_data

"%CD%\mcp_data\Java\bin\java.exe" -Xmx3072m -Dorg.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL=true -jar "%CD%\mcp_data\launcher\MineCraft.jar"
```

Comment: hi, my intention is to use the java version on the flashdrive. Even when I include \java.exe at the end of the "set JAVA_HOME" path, it still comes up with "java is not a recognizable internal or external command"

Comment: Right. But use the full path to the exe. Like, if i go on my system "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" , it works whether java is set in the path or not. Since your java binary is on the flash drive, the location is never changing, you may as well hardcode it into your bat file to avoid any path problems. If that doesn't work, maybe your school has some slightly clever security set up to block Java at all costs.

Comment: How would you set the full path when on a flash drive the drive letter changes constantly? That's why I wanted to use %CD%

Comment: Oh, opps! i used the wrong variable. you want to use %~d0% , which will give you the Drive letter that the bat file originates on. So you use "%~d0%\mcp_data\Java\bin\java.exe" and it will always target the java.exe on the drive your flash drive is mounted on.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and get back with the results!

Comment: Unfortunatley that still did not work - I know this computer allows Java becuase if I place the minecraft.exe on the desktop it opens fine (Except it tells me bad opengl drivers - this can be fixed with a custom batch file). Any other ideas?

Comment: What error did it give? Everything i've read said this should work at this point...

Comment: "Java is not recognized as an internal or external commend, operable program or batch file" Here, if you would like to look at the entire setup here is a link to the download. http://www.mediafire.com/download/ncxpeg78r3srnnl/Minecraft+Portable+1.3.5.zip

Comment: It works fine with my home laptop, but not with the school computer (java installed) OR my desktop at home (no java installed). This probably means its not being pointed to the flash drive's version of java.

Comment: Updated comment again, use that exactly.

Comment: @user1808010: On StackOverflow "thanks" is said by upvoting and accepting answers :)

Comment: as you can see by the up vote on his answer, I already did that. How do I accept an answer though?

Comment: There should be something shaped like checkmark under the button you clicked to upvote the answer, click on it